# VPNs chain to bypass blocked VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, l2tp, strongswan

I have an L2TP VPN server that is blocked in my country.
Is it possible to configure middle/jump server to make a chain like that:
`PC -> VPN1 -> VPN2 -> Internet`
VPN1 is hosted by a cloud service (can be any dist).
I don't have access to VPN2, just credentials to L2TP.
Any connection to VPN1 is possible (Wireguard, OpenVPN, through SSH tunnel, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

1. At your VPN1 host  you should  setup a   VPN1->VPN2 routing tunnel.
2. Setup iptables MASQUERADE PC->VPN1 link (to make NAT work)